# How to run Selenium in Aegis Blade

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a simple selenium task using Firefox on [Aegis Blade](https://www.aegisblade.com). I am hitting some errors though.

I set my api key:

```sh
$ export AEGISBLADE_API_KEY="my-api-key"
```

Then run this code:

```py
from aegisblade import aegisblade
from selenium import webdriver

def gethtml(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    return driver.page_source


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running AegisBlade job")
    job = aegisblade.run(lambda: gethtml("https://github.com"))

    print("Waiting for job to finish...")
    print(job.get_return_value())
```

I receive the following error though:

```
Internal Error Type: WebDriverException
Internal Error: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I am using Python 2.7, but it doesn't look like that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AegisBlade will automatically detect your pip dependencies (selenium in this case), but doesn't have the same functionality for dependencies defined outside of the package manager.

In short, you must request that AegisBlade make the web driver's dependencies available during the runtime of your job.

[There is a selenium example on Github.](https://github.com/aegisblade/examples)

Here is your code, slightly altered, so that it works:

```py
from aegisblade import aegisblade, JobConfig, Capability
from selenium import webdriver

def gethtml(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    return driver.page_source


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running AegisBlade job")
    config = JobConfig().with_capability(Capability.firefox)
    job = aegisblade.run(lambda: gethtml("https://github.com"), config)

    print("Waiting for job to finish...")
    print(job.get_return_value())
```

P.S. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. [I responded to you on Github with a little more depth.](https://github.com/aegisblade/aegisblade/issues/1)